# how do I compare the volumes of different watches in pine?

Tags: pine-script

how can pine compare the volume at 13.00 of the current day with the volumes at 11.00 and 12.00 of the current day and how to compare the volume at 13.00 with the volume at 13.00 of each of the previous 7 days?

I'm new to pine. I do not know how to combine Volume[] and the clock (1 hour, 4 hours) in New York time